# Write to multiple files in parallel in Rust

Tags: multithreading, file, rust

In Rust, I need to store data entries produced by multiple threads as gzip files, similar to how logging systems store data into log files and auto-rotates them as they get too big, but I need to multi-thread as much as possible. My rough idea of the process:

- a callback gets data entries from multiple threads, processes them, and adds them to a queue to be stored
- multiple gzip sinks pick up entries from the queue, compress and store them into gzip files
- when gzip sink exceeds some number of entries, it should finish the file and start a new one

I am very new to Rust, so not sure if this is a correct "Rusty" pattern/architecture. Having a central entry queue seem like a possible bottleneck, or not? What libs or multithreading primitives would fit this task?  Thanks!

Comment: Please share the code you have so far. Because you have tried to solve the problem yourself, right?

Comment: It's unclear whether the threads which produce the data should themselves write gzip files. I'm assuming the gzip-writing is detached, but should happen in parallel as well. In this case I would send each thread's produced data to an mpsc::channel, the receiver can pick it up and assign it to a worker. There are convenience libraries such as https://crates.io/crates/workerpool which make this rather easy. For your rotating requirements you'd need a stateful worker to keep track of the size.